# developing a IOT device using GSM 7600E

Tags: gsm

I am using a SIM7600E module, the module connects to the network and AT+CREG returns 0,5 and when I check the signal quality using AT+CSQ returns 11,99.
I am getting a bit error rate (ber) as 99, idk if this can cause problems during communication. As i am unable to send text messages or connect to the GPRS network as i am not assigned any IP(AT+CGREG returns 0,5)?
Is there anyway to improve the ber 99?